# Select repeated cases from a variable

Tags: r, select, measure

I am working with a database called `Visitas`. It is a visits database from a hospital in which the variable `codeep` represents the code of the patient. As the patients go to the hospital frequently, the patients have more than one measure. The variable in which they have more than one measure is called `result`, coded with the same code patient in the variable `codeep` each time they get a result in the `result` variable.

What I want is to get all the positions in the `codeep` variable, from each patient, in order to get the mean from the variable `result`, for each patient.

As an example, I present what I want for just one patient. I used `which()` and in return I get the vector with the positions where this code is repeated in the `codeep` variable. Now I would like to make this for all the patients, automatized.

In order to get this I tried a loop but it doesn't work, but maybe is my code.

```
which(Visitas[,'codeep'] == 6208)

# One loop

for (i in Visitas[, 'codeep']) {
    Visitas_TRT[i] <- which(Visitas$codeep[i] == Visitas$codeep)
} 

# Double loop

for (i in Visitas[, 'codeep']) {
  for (j in Visitas[, 'codeep']) {
    Visitas_TRT <- which(Visitas$codeep[i] == Visitas$codeep[j])
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

[This is head the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM3a7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you're looking for `ave`, with which you may create a variable with the `mean` of `result` by each `codeep`.

```
Visitas <- transform(Visitas, result.M=ave(result, codeep, FUN=mean))
Visitas
#    codeep today result result.M
# 1       1     1    6.4 5.866667
# 2       2     1    4.4 6.066667
# 3       3     1    5.4 4.633333
# 4       4     1    5.6 5.766667
# 5       5     1    5.4 5.066667
# 6       1     2    4.9 5.866667
# 7       2     2    6.5 6.066667
# 8       3     2    4.9 4.633333
# 9       4     2    7.0 5.766667
# 10      5     2    4.9 5.066667
# 11      1     3    6.3 5.866667
# 12      2     3    7.3 6.066667
# 13      3     3    3.6 4.633333
# 14      4     3    4.7 5.766667
# 15      5     3    4.9 5.066667
```

---

*Data:*

```
Visitas <- expand.grid(codeep=1:5, today=1:3)
set.seed(42)
Visitas$result <- round(rnorm(nrow(Visitas), 5), 1)
```

Comment: Yes I think it works, it was quite simple but I did not know this function. Thank you so much! @jay.sf

Comment: Sorry, what you wrote here is okay but I would like to get all the values from each patient besides of getting the mean. Because I have to calculate  the percentage of the number of times that the patient is between the limits, not only the mean. Do you know how could I get this? @jay.sf

Comment: @CarlosPascualBosch It's possible to define any function in `ave`, also anonymous functions such as `FUN=function(x) sum(x > L1 & x < L2)`. Does this help you?

Comment: Yes it's what I am trying now. I hope I can get it, thank you again @jay.sf

Comment: You're welcome @CarlosPascualBosch! Report back if it doesn't work. Please consider to [mark answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).